# Генерирование картинки в PHP

Tags: графика, php

На этой [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4474/alex_90/flair/) внизу <strike>лежит</strike> флаер. Он генерируется "на лету". Как на `PHP` сделать такую же штуку? 
[image]

Comment: Не понятно где флаер, какой-нибудь screen-shot приведите, а то не понятно о чем идет речь

Comment: Сорри, сейчас исправлюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего используется [GD](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) для рисования такой картинки плюс [Gravatar](http://ru.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/) для получения самого аватара. Дело не особо хитрое.

Answer (score 1):

Я ради интереса написал подобную фигнюшку.
Если интересно, могу выслать весь код(Warning: он непричесанный)

Если вкратце - берем хэш от какой-то уникальной величины(например, e-mail), делим его на блоки. Первые 6 символов - отдаем под цвет бэкграунда, остальное делим поровну между координатами точек(граватар калейдоскоп делает чуть иначе: у него изначально все паттерны заданы), потом размножаем с поворотом в четыре раза.

Comment: А, вы это про граватар? Я имел в виду в общем как текст в картинку переделать.

Comment: Хотя про граватар тоже интересно было узнать.

Comment: Просто текст рисуется при помощи простой функции http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagepstext.php